# UIViewController does not show up when class starts

Tags: ios, swift

I start a UIViewController and method viewDidLoad fires up.  However the actual view does not show until all other code has executed.  Why ?

```
class Mall_restore_2: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            println("started Mall_restore_2")
            restore_map()        // this executes for 20-30 seconds
====view appears now, i.e. after 30 seconds delay =========
   }
```

The view controller is instantiated via:

```
    self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Mall_restore_2_panel") as! Mall_restore_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've identified the problem, it's linked to your long running task. Long task should not run in main thread.

Here is how to do it in Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
 restore_map() 
})
```

This will rune the restore_map function in the default background queue....
Once this will be finished, you can call an update function in the main thread or send a message.

For instance:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
 restore_map() 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update your UI following the restore_map function
  }
})
```

Comment: override func viewDidAppear() {
            println("at view did appear")
        }

Comment: Not sure about the meaning of the comment @MicheleDiblasi?

Comment: tried to add viewDidAppear, but it comes up as error (Method does not override any method from its superclass)

Comment: if i add the dispatch_async nothing happens (I'm sure it runs in background).  Need to read up about dispatch queues to find out how this works.

Comment: By "nothing happens" what do you mean: the view display correctly but the result of restore map is not taken in account?

Comment: sorry, msg goes when you press return halfway thru msg,  anyway controller does not come up till after the long running 'restore_map'.  I have moved it to execute at viewDidAppear and looks better. thanks

Comment: But be careful, by doing it after the viewDidAppear you are just "masking" the problem, not solving it. You should not do such heavy process in the display thread....

Comment: yes, you are correct. I did notice that results look faked.  New at IOS. will have to do more research as what I really need is to update the view while the long task is running to show progress.  Can do it in Android, now I need to find equivalent. thanks

Comment: Suggestion: - put a UIActivityIndicatorView in your view, this will display a spinning animation during you will do the update in the background, and once finished, just stop it ...(and don't forget to mark the answer as OK on SO! ;) )

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad()` is called when the view is loading but before it appears. To run the code after the view appears, call it in the `viewDidAppear()` method.

In addition, any operation that will take a noticeable amount of time should be run in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your "restore_map()" function may be too heavy and running on the main thread, so if you have any kind of loop inside of it, or any "long" processing, you should divide it in smaller functions and do it async (multi thread), so you will have a smoother experience. If you don't know how to do that, please, access this link: [Ray Wenderlich: Swift - GCD Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Are you running that on simulator or on debug mode connected to the device? If is that so, try to disconnect the device and open the application, some times the debug mode is way heavier than it should and take a lot of time to load.

Comment: By the way: in Swift/Objective-C Apple calls the use of CamelCase instead of underline, as a good practice.